# WSL2 Dockerfile not building - DNS problems

Tags: docker, wsl-2

I´m using WSL2 on Windows with Ubuntu, I had problems with PIP, it gave me DNS problems, so I modified the file /ect/resolve.conf , after this I was able to use PIP, but still I have problems with the Dockerfile.

when using docker build, and trying to use pip install requirements.txt, it tries to download the packages from the requirements file and got DNS problems.

so, how can I add DNS servernames to the Dockerfile? or how can I solve this issue?

Regards.

Comment: I found a workaround here https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4285

Comment: which of the plenty workarounds there worked for you?

Comment: Hi Benni, unfortunately the workaround crashed in a few days, I made many changes and I'm not sure which worked, at the end I moved to Linux to work in the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue, some domains can't be resolved during `docker build`.
Here is the content of the `/etc/resolv.conf` from one of my built images:

- cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
# DNS requests are forwarded to the host. DHCP DNS options are ignored.
nameserver 192.168.65.7
```

I couldn't find this IP either in my Windows 10 or in my Ubuntu WSL2 :o

Answer (score 0):

In case any one else is having this issue, I'll share what worked for me. I've been in the Windows world so long that I forgot about one of the basic linux DNS config files. I just updated /etc/resolv.conf and was then able to resolve DNS names just fine.

Comment: You'll likely lose this on reboot or the next time you restart WSL as it regenerates `/etc/resolv.conf`